# Problema ao instalar o JasperReport Server 5.6.1 no Windwos 8.1

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports

Boa noite!

Estou tendo problema ao instalar o JasperReportServer 5.6.1 no meu Windows 8.1 com o Java 8.

Eu fiz o download o JasperReports Server no link [jasperReportsServer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases) .
Baixei o arquivo jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1-windows-x64-installer.exe

Instalei tudo direitinho ele já instala junto o Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 até ai tudo bem.

Quando eu vou consegui abrir o **Tomcat Web Application Manager** conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se analisar a **List Applications** tem o **/jasperserver**, que está como veio do download.

E quando eu clico em Start para iniciar o Servidor da o seguinte erro:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /jasperserver could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jasperserver]]
```

Mais informação...
Quando eu vou iniciar o tom cat da o seguinte errono arquivo de log catalina.2014-12-03.log

```
dez 03, 2014 11:35:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMAÇÕES: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4.6.
dez 03, 2014 11:35:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMAÇÕES: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
dez 03, 2014 11:35:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFORMAÇÕES: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013)
dez 03, 2014 11:35:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]
dez 03, 2014 11:35:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
dez 03, 2014 11:35:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 3750 ms
dez 03, 2014 11:35:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
dez 03, 2014 11:35:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
dez 03, 2014 11:35:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreportsserver\apache-tomcat\webapps\host-manager
dez 03, 2014 11:35:11 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFORMAÇÕES: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [118] milliseconds.
dez 03, 2014 11:35:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreportsserver\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver
dez 03, 2014 11:35:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jasperserver]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 21 more
```

Alguém já passou por um erro parecido com esse?

Obrigado!

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig`, parece que você precisa de uma versão do Jersey no Classpath.

Comment: Cara eu n sei bem quem é esse Jersey, eu preciso instala ele? eu já tenho ele? como coloco ele no Classpath? Obrigado

Comment: Oi Anderson. Eu não tenho muita experiência com o JasperReports Server, desse forma desconheço suas dependências a procedimentos de instalação (existe um manual de instalação [no seu link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases)). Dito isso, o [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) é uma das mais populares implementações de [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) (API para Web Services RESTFul). Geralmente colocamos as bibliotecas na pasta do war `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Alternativamente o Tomcat possui mecanismos para lidar com bibliotecas comuns compartilhadas entre as aplicações (veja [o Manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).